# Buttons in AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Hello I'm trying to add buttons to my Appwidget, but even after reading many codes, my buttons aren't working.

This is my AppWidgetProvider:
    public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            intent.setAction("0");
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);


            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_widget, pendingIntent);


            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
        }
    }
```

And here is MyService:

```
public class MyService extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String command = intent.getAction();
        int[] appWidgetIds = intent
        .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());


        if (command.equals("0")) {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button_widget, "TextChanged");
        }

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widgetlayout);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteView);


        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        return 0;
    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is just a dummy code that is supposed to changed a button's text when you click it. It doesn't.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i just take a look in your source code, it seem problem belong logic, 
your re-create new RemoteView object after your change text content:

**Solution:** Comment out following line of code:

```
    /* 22/07/2011 DELETE START */
    //RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
    //        R.layout.widgetlayout);
    /* 22/07/2011 DELETE END */
```

In class MyService:

```
public class MyService extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String command = intent.getAction();
        int[] appWidgetIds = intent
        .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                .getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());


        if (command.equals("0")) {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button_widget, "TextChanged");
        }

        /* 22/07/2011 DELETE START */
        //RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
        //        R.layout.widgetlayout);
        /* 22/07/2011 DELETE END */    
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteView);


        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        return 0;
    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Removed it, and changed the line in the if to remoteView.etc instead of remoteViews.etc    still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code from  `onStartCommand` into

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
```

as you might run your code on older Android platforms that only use onStart.